# PHP Phar archive creation fails

Tags: php, phar

I'm trying to create a tar archive with PHP Phar. I've got about 8500 files in a directory and use the following code:

```
try {
    $tmp_archive = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'arc') . ".tar";
    $a = new PharData($tmp_archive);

    $a->buildFromDirectory('/tmp/data');
    $a->compress(Phar::GZ);
    unset ($a);

    unlink($tmp_archive);
    rename ($tmp_archive . ".gz", '/tmp/result.tar.gz');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Tar exception : " . $e;
}
```

It fails during this process with the following message:

> Tar exception : exception 'PharException' with message 'tar-based phar "/tmp/arcRoYeOC.tar" cannot be created, contents of file "3147.pdf" could not be written, seek failed' in /tmp/test.php:9

Does anyone know how to get around this? Shall I just use the command line to do this with tar instead?

Comment: In line 9 you seem to be unlinking the archive you have just created. Why would you do that?

Comment: @HoboSapiens  no I'm unlinking the tar, not the .tar.gz - this is because of the compress creating the .tar.gz but not removing the .tar

Comment: Please note : the function tempnam() *creates* a file named 'tmpdir/arcxxx', and returns the name as a string, and only then you add '.tar' to this string. You end up with an empty temporary file that you never use and never delete

Comment: Did you try it on a very small directory with just 2-3 files ? There may be a scale/size problem?

Comment: @Zimmi Yeah this works well for a hundred files or so

Comment: which size are the files you want to put into the phar? how large is a .tar and .tar.gz file you manually create with `gzip`?